# Убрать верхнюю панель

Tags: android-navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, bottom-navigation-view

мне нужно убрать верхнюю панель в режиме навигации. Пересмотрел все сайты и не нашел ответа, ее вообще можно убрать или она будет такой всегда?[image: Вот какую панель надо убрать]

Comment: Там две панели ActionBar / Toolbar (фиолетовый цвет) и statusbar (синий цвет). Это раздельные элементы, который из них хотите убрать? Ну и первый из них задается в верстке, так что покажите ее

Comment: мне надо убрать панель Dashboard, она меняется когда я перехожу по кнопкам ,то что написано на кнопке то и наверху ,а мне это не надо.  А та панель где время ,заряд телефона и тд мне надо оставить

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте в разделе application - themes выбрать тему noactionbar или fullscreen или notitlebar

Comment: Когда я ввjжу стиль noactionbar у меня вылетает приложение при запуске эмулятора и при запуске на телефон так же. Я это уже пробовал ,щас попробовал еще раз ,результат тот же. А варианты notitlebar и fullscreen у меня вообще не принимаются ,т.к. у меня шаблон изначально создан как Button Navigation activity.

Comment: В поиске выдает много решений по скрытию actionbar. Попробуйте что-либо